# New Oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle, data-dictionary

When I create an Oracle database it has a lot of tables in it with strange names. What are these tables? Should I keep them? If not, how can I avoid creating them?

These are the table names:

> LOGMNR_UID$ LOGMNR_SESSION_EVOLVE$
>   LOGMNR_GLOBAL$
>   LOGMNR_RESTART_CKPT_TXINFO$
>   LOGMNR_AGE_SPILL$ LOGMNR_SPILL$
>   LOGMNRC_DBNAME_UID_MAP LOGMNR_LOG$
>   LOGMNR_ERROR$ LOGMNR_PROCESSED_LOG$
>   LOGMNR_FILTER$ LOGMNR_RESTART_CKPT$
>   LOGMNR_GT_TAB_INCLUDE$
>   LOGMNR_GT_USER_INCLUDE$ LOGMNRT_MDDL$
>   OL$ OL$HINTS OL$NODES
>   LOGMNR_DICTSTATE$ LOGMNRC_GTLO
>   LOGMNRC_GTCS LOGMNRC_GSII LOGMNR_SEED$
>   LOGMNR_DICTIONARY$ LOGMNR_OBJ$
>   LOGMNR_TAB$ LOGMNR_COL$
>   LOGMNR_ATTRCOL$ LOGMNR_TS$ LOGMNR_IND$
>   LOGMNR_USER$ LOGMNR_TABPART$
>   LOGMNR_TABSUBPART$ LOGMNR_TABCOMPART$
>   LOGMNR_TYPE$ LOGMNR_COLTYPE$
>   LOGMNR_ATTRIBUTE$ LOGMNR_LOB$
>   LOGMNR_CDEF$ LOGMNR_CCOL$ LOGMNR_ICOL$
>   LOGMNR_LOBFRAG$ LOGMNR_INDPART$
>   LOGMNR_INDSUBPART$ LOGMNR_INDCOMPART$
>   LOGMNR_LOGMNR_BUILDLOG LOGMNR_NTAB$
>   LOGMNR_OPQTYPE$ LOGMNR_SUBCOLTYPE$
>   LOGMNR_KOPM$ LOGMNR_PROPS$ LOGMNR_ENC$
>   LOGMNR_REFCON$ LOGMNR_PARTOBJ$
>   LOGMNRP_CTAS_PART_MAP
>   LOGSTDBY$APPLY_PROGRESS MVIEW$_ADV_OWB
>   DEF$_AQERROR DEF$_AQCALL
>   MVIEW$_ADV_PARTITION MVIEW$_ADV_INDEX
>   HELP SQLPLUS_PRODUCT_PROFILE
>   LOGSTDBY$HISTORY LOGSTDBY$SKIP_SUPPORT
>   LOGSTDBY$SKIP
>   LOGSTDBY$SKIP_TRANSACTION
>   LOGSTDBY$PLSQL LOGSTDBY$FLASHBACK_SCN
>   LOGSTDBY$SCN LOGSTDBY$APPLY_MILESTONE
>   LOGSTDBY$EVENTS LOGSTDBY$PARAMETERS
>   REPCAT$_SITES_NEW REPCAT$_EXTENSION
>   REPCAT$_INSTANTIATION_DDL
>   REPCAT$_EXCEPTIONS
>   REPCAT$_TEMPLATE_TARGETS
>   REPCAT$_RUNTIME_PARMS
>   REPCAT$_SITE_OBJECTS
>   REPCAT$_TEMPLATE_SITES
>   REPCAT$_USER_PARM_VALUES
>   REPCAT$_OBJECT_PARMS
>   REPCAT$_TEMPLATE_PARMS
>   REPCAT$_TEMPLATE_OBJECTS
>   REPCAT$_TEMPLATE_REFGROUPS
>   REPCAT$_OBJECT_TYPES
>   REPCAT$_USER_AUTHORIZATIONS
>   REPCAT$_REFRESH_TEMPLATES
>   REPCAT$_TEMPLATE_TYPES
>   REPCAT$_TEMPLATE_STATUS
>   REPCAT$_FLAVOR_OBJECTS
>   REPCAT$_AUDIT_COLUMN
>   REPCAT$_AUDIT_ATTRIBUTE
>   REPCAT$_PARAMETER_COLUMN
>   REPCAT$_RESOL_STATS_CONTROL
>   REPCAT$_RESOLUTION_STATISTICS
>   REPCAT$_RESOLUTION
>   REPCAT$_RESOLUTION_METHOD
>   REPCAT$_CONFLICT
>   REPCAT$_GROUPED_COLUMN
>   REPCAT$_COLUMN_GROUP REPCAT$_PRIORITY
>   REPCAT$_PRIORITY_GROUP
>   REPCAT$_REPGROUP_PRIVS REPCAT$_DDL
>   REPCAT$_REPCATLOG REPCAT$_REPPROP
>   REPCAT$_GENERATED REPCAT$_KEY_COLUMNS
>   REPCAT$_REPCOLUMN REPCAT$_REPOBJECT
>   REPCAT$_SNAPGROUP REPCAT$_REPSCHEMA
>   REPCAT$_FLAVORS REPCAT$_REPCAT
>   DEF$_PUSHED_TRANSACTIONS DEF$_ORIGIN
>   DEF$_PROPAGATOR DEF$_TEMP$LOB DEF$_LOB
>   DEF$_DEFAULTDEST DEF$_CALLDEST
>   DEF$_DESTINATION DEF$_ERROR
>   AQ$_INTERNET_AGENT_PRIVS
>   AQ$_INTERNET_AGENTS AQ$_SCHEDULES
>   AQ$_QUEUES AQ$_QUEUE_TABLES
>   MVIEW$_ADV_PLAN MVIEW$_ADV_JOURNAL
>   MVIEW$_ADV_INFO MVIEW$_ADV_PARAMETERS
>   MVIEW$_ADV_EXCEPTIONS
>   MVIEW$_ADV_OUTPUT MVIEW$_ADV_ELIGIBLE
>   MVIEW$_ADV_CLIQUE MVIEW$_ADV_GC
>   MVIEW$_ADV_FJG MVIEW$_ADV_AJG
>   MVIEW$_ADV_ROLLUP MVIEW$_ADV_LEVEL
>   MVIEW$_ADV_FILTERINSTANCE
>   MVIEW$_ADV_LOG MVIEW$_ADV_FILTER
>   MVIEW$_ADV_TEMP MVIEW$_ADV_PRETTY
>   MVIEW$_ADV_SQLDEPEND
>   MVIEW$_ADV_BASETABLE
>   MVIEW$_ADV_WORKLOAD LOGMNR_SESSION$
>   LOGMNR_PARAMETER$

Comment: Generally, or do you want a list of what they all mean?

Comment: No. I want to know if I need whole of them or not.

Comment: They haven't created them for fun. If you aren't sure, don't touch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tables you have listed relate to Oracle's [LogMiner utility](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/utility.htm#i10918), [Materialized Views](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm) and [Advanced Replication](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14226/toc.htm) among other things.  You should leave these alone.

Answer (score 6):

It is called the data dictionary, where Oracle stores information on its modules and tables. See the [Oracle documentation](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/search?remark=quick_search&word=data+dictionary).

If you select custom installation, you may select to not [install modules](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/readmes.112/e11015/toc.htm). Which gives you less modules, and a smaller data dictionary.